# 2 way modification with an array

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with many tabs representing a location with an inventory. In every tabs, there's a column with a chez box to state if that item as to be moved to a new building. I made an array in another tab (filter tab) that filter all the items that the box is checked. Because it's an array, I can't modify the item in the filter tab, have to go on the original tab where it comes from to modify it.  Is there any way I can modify in the filter tab and have that modification change also in the original tab?

Here the array function I use in the filter tab.

```
=QUERY({'SALLE 1'!A:H;'SALLE 2'!A:H;'SALLE 3'!A:H;'SALLE 4'!A:H;'SALLE 5'!A:H;'SALLE 6'!A:H;'SALLE 7'!A:H;'SALLE 8'!A:H;'SALLE 9'!A:H;'SALLE 10'!A:H};"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where (Col5='X' or Col5='x')")
```

Answer (score 0):

no, that is not possible to do in Google Sheets. you can't reference the reference nor create two-directional references and create paradoxes